# Set default welcome message on index with menu included

Tags: php

I have a website where I include everything trough a index.switch.php,

So When someone log in the header location is: website.com with a blank content div, and the menu loaded on the left.

How can I set a welcome's message on the index (content div) without showing it on every other page, because I include everything.

I hope you guys understand what I, else I show some code or pictures..

Thanxs!

Comment: i guess some code would be useful. How does index.switch works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you change the content of the header in the index.switch.php file?

I guess it would be something like:

```
$header='';
if($page=='whatever'){
$header="your message";
include "the_page_with_the_message.php";
}
```

Then in header.php just:

```
echo $header;
```

wherever you want the message to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "path.to.page") {
    include "welcome.php"
}
```